# Is there a way to include twitter search results in a Sharepoint page?

Tags: twitter

What I am looking is to have a column where I can see what is new on twitter under a specific tag, ex #sharepoint

I am using Sharepoint as part of Office 365, it is our enterprise server and I am a regular user having my own site

Comment: Use this Twitter web part if you are using SharePoint online: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-twitter-web-part-15db6b3b-d167-41dd-9875-2af64b44d820

Comment: thank you, so there is no way to add it directly without creating the collection under your own account prior to that or find a collection created by someone else

Comment: You can also show "Tweets from a user feed": like `@microsoft`

Comment: That was clear from the beginning. I was looking for  filtered list of tweets with a specific tag

Comment: For specific tag, you have to create a collection or check if this custom web part helps: https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-twitter